# Prisma / How can i use base entity(model)?

Tags: prisma, radix

I want use BaseEntity like TypeORM in Prisma

This is my example code

```
model Test1 {
  id   Int    @id
  name String @db.VarChar(30)
  base Base
}

model Test2{
  id Int @id
  name String @db.VarchAr(30)
  base Base
}

model Base {
  reg_id  String   @db.Char(12)
  reg_dt  DateTime @default(now()) @db.DateTime(6)
  edit_id String   @db.Char(12)
  edit_dt DateTime @updatedAt @db.DateTime(6)
}
```

But it's not working, how can i solve this?
help me please..

my prisma version is "prisma": "4.16.2",

```
model Test1 {
  id   Int    @id
  name String @db.VarChar(30)
  base Base
}

model Test2{
  id Int @id
  name String @db.VarchAr(30)
  base Base
}

model Base {
  reg_id  String   @db.Char(12)
  reg_dt  DateTime @default(now()) @db.DateTime(6)
  edit_id String   @db.Char(12)
  edit_dt DateTime @updatedAt @db.DateTime(6)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this feature is not currently supported in Prisma. You can track the progress in [this issue](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/12604) or [this one](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/2371).

For now you have to copypaste these fields, or use some third party tools, but I don't have a recommendation for a good working tool (check issues for more info).